# CentOS httpd 403 Forbidden

Tags: centos, httpd, apache2

I recently setup my first CentOS7 (64-Bit) server.
Previously I used Debian.
I set up httpd with 2 simple vHosts but all I see in the browser is Error `403`.
I made 2 folders in `/var/www` which are named as the domains are.
In those folders I put a simple .htm file which outputs only a few words.
After that I gave `777` permissions (for testing only) to my `www` and all other subfolders and files.

Later I created the `sites-available` and `sites-enabled` folders in `/etc/httpd`.

Then I made the vHost file `jonas-heinze.de.conf` `and projectaes.net.conf` (same name as the folders in `www`) and put

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName jonas-heinze.de
     DocumentRoot /var/www/jonas-heinze.de
</VirtualHost>
```

and

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName projectaes.net
     DocumentRoot /var/www/projectaes.net
</VirtualHost>
```

inside.

To activate the vHosts I used `sudo ln -s /etc/httpd/sites-available/jonas-heinze.de.conf /etc/httpd/sites-enabled/jonas-heinze.de.conf`
and `sudo ln -s /etc/httpd/sites-available/projectaes.net.conf /etc/httpd/sites-enabled/projectaes.net.conf` and although put `IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf` inside my `httpd.conf`.

Online I saw something about a special permission system used in CentOS so I have run the `sudo setsebool -P httpd_unified 1` command.

But if I connect with jonas-heinze.de all I get is a 403 Error screen.

`getenforce` returned a `disabled` .

Additional I disabled `Selinux` in `/etc/selinux/config` and checked the Syntax of `httpd.conf` .

I run `httpd -S` and it returned

```
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   jonas-heinze.de (/etc/httpd/sites-enabled/jonas-heinze.de                                                                                                                     .conf:1)
ServerRoot: "/etc/httpd"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/html"
Main ErrorLog: "/etc/httpd/logs/error_log"
Mutex proxy: using_defaults
Mutex authn-socache: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="/run/httpd/" mechanism=default
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
Mutex authdigest-opaque: using_defaults
Mutex proxy-balancer-shm: using_defaults
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
Mutex authdigest-client: using_defaults
PidFile: "/run/httpd/httpd.pid"
Define: _RH_HAS_HTTPPROTOCOLOPTIONS
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="apache" id=48
Group: name="apache" id=48
```

It looks like the Main DocumentRoot is wrong. So I created an `index.html` in that one.

Comment: A couple of basic questions:
1. Does the hostname jonas-heinze.de resolve properly?  I.e. can you ping this host from your client system (the one the browser is running on?
2. Do you have actual content (e.g. an index.html) in /var/www/jonas-heinze.de ?

Comment: 1. The hostname resolves properly (TS3 is working, nslookup returns the correct ip, correct ip set in DNS).
I tried to connect using Firefox and Chrome using Windows 10.
I can ping my server.

2. As I said I have an `index.htm` in /var/www/jonas-heinze.de. :)

Comment: I haven't tried to configure apache on CentOS, but this "Later I created the sites-available and sites-enabled folders in /etc/httpd" makes me think that perhaps the primary httpd configuration file isn't configured by default to read the contents of sites-enabled?  On Debian/Ubuntu this is set up by default.  I run apache on Arch Linux servers as well, and there I have to explicitly tell it to read the vhosts files; e..g `Include sites-enabled/jonas-heinze.de.conf`  Check your httpd.conf file to make sure it's actually reading the vhost files.  Also, at least when debugging, turn off selinux.

Comment: I added `Include sites-enabled/jonas-heinze.de.conf` to httpd.conf.
Sadly it didn't worked. I also tried multiple variants. Still the sae result.
I wasn't sure if the sites-* folder were readable so I updated the permissions. Still the same result.

Comment: Did you remember to restart httpd after adding the Include line?  The configuration files are only read when the daemon is started.

Comment: BTW I was able to see the standard webpage before I tried to make the vHosts.

Comment: I restarted httpd to try all variants of the Including line

Comment: I updated the question by a couple of lines.

Comment: Try removing the Include line and put the <VirtualHost *:80> directives directly inside the httpd.conf file, then restart httpd.  If that doesn't work, I'm at a loss for what could be wrong (assuming you remembered to turn off selinux).  Also, in a terminal on the machine running apache, what happens when you try this `w3m jonas-heinze.de`?  (You will probably need to install w3m, which is a text-based web browser.

Comment: My server don't know the command w3m. That with the Include is not working.
Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: That's normal: you need to install it:  `yum install w3m`

Comment: @pgoetz,
thanks for all your ideas and effort you put into my question.
But the friend I share the server with was able to fix the issue.
Have a nice day
Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was, that the webserver wasn't able to handle `.htm` files.
But the index files were `.htm` .
I had to allow the usage of `.htm` files in a `.conf`.
Unfortunately I don't remember where the file. D:

I hope, that might help users with the same issue.